# How to set ASCII (SBCS) character sets for a project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I have a project with `/D "UNICODE" /D "_UNICODE"` flags set in the `C/C++ Command Line`. Unfortunately I can't edit this flags (the edit field is disabled). What flag i have to add in the `Additional Options` filed to tell the compiler i wanna use just `ASCII charset` instead of `UNICODE`?

Comment: Under the project properties->advanced select Use Multi-Byte Character Set instead of Use Unicode Character Set. Be sure to select All Configurations and All Platforms at the top first.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Does setting this to `Multi-Byte Character Set ` makes the compiler to use 8-bit, single-byte-character set (SBCS) as I've asked?

Comment: Those are the two options you have available. If you are using Windows functions they would map to the A version instead of the W version. If you only use ASCII character then they will be single bytes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So setting to `Multi-Byte Character Set` make the compiler to mat to  A version instead of the W versions (what i would like to achieve)?

Comment: @Derek81 Yes it does.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry friend but it DESN'T helped. I still gets the compilation errors like:  `cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [65]' to 'LPCWSTR'` and under the investigation of the function i've discovered it still maps to W instead of A.

Comment: Well, I can't see your code or your project. Perhaps you have UNICODE defined elsewhere or you didn't change all platforms and targets. What I described is the right way to switch between the two on a normal project.

Comment: After setting Multi-Byte Character Set, did the flags "UNICODE"  "_UNICODE" disappear?   In addition, please check whether the page you modified is the `Active` property page.